# How do you create a GIF file from the gif image retrieved from a users camera roll using the swift programming language in IOS development?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, gif, ios-camera

I am using a library called YPImagePicker (https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker?utm_source=mybridge&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=read_more)  through GitHub to facilitate the media selection in the app that I am working on. The issue that I am having is that when a gif file is selected from the camera roll, it is saved as a JPEG image data internally which doesn't allow it to be saved as a gif image data under the hood. I have meticulously traced the underlying code but to no avail. To solve the problem I tried doing the following: 1. I first captured the raw image taken from the camera roll and checked if its meta-data contained a "GIF" format [capturing the gif image from the camera roll and checking its metadata for GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX2BO.png).  2. Then I used a helper class to create the image data and create a file URL for the image so that it can be used when creating the form POST request to the server [helper class that creates a file for the newly captured gif image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFRB6.png). That helper class utilizes a UIImage extension that I received from an answer on stack overflow [helper UIImage extension that creates image data based on the underlying image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIfuB.png). The problem that I am having is that the supposed GIF files are still being outputted as mere JPEG files. I am unsure if the problem starts with the library or with, my custom implementation solutions. In the app when a user finishes selecting the GIF image from their camera roll, the image is displayed as still and not animating. By best guess is that the problem occurs when the image is actually retrieved from the camera roll. The library uses the PHotoKit framework and ImageIO framework. I don't know if I should refactor the libraries' code to fit my needs or dump the library altogether and implement a solution from scratch. Once again the libraries git repository is https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker?utm_source=mybridge&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=read_more

Comment: If you wonderfull developers have any tips on how I can learn the underlying Image framework in IOS so that I can have a full understanding of Image data and data in general, that would be greatly appreciated. I have heard about the CoreImage and UIIMage frameworks but that's about it.

Comment: try selecting the file without the library, using UIImagePickerViewController and see what you get from that